# Flex - three columns, the 3d one goes beyond the screen

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

When running this code, the right column goes long beyond the screen, rightward.

1. I want the side columns to be responsive, while the middle one to be with a fixed width.
2. And how to make it working in IE10?

Layout:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget ante bibendum, cursus diam sit amet
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper .left {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.wrapper .middle {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 800px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.wrapper .right {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the `flex` shorthand properly.
This is the correct format:
`flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink>? || <flex-basis> ;`

Ive changed yours to work with your specifications including IE. Because of the 800ox fixed width you'll need to view this in full screen.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper .left {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.wrapper .middle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.wrapper .right {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget ante bibendum, cursus diam sit amet
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help, If you could mark my answer as correct please, by checking the tick next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex: 1; on it's own for your left and right columns. You don't really need to specify the flex-shrink and flex-basis values as they will be set sensibly depending on the flex-grow property.

Comment: This would be true except for IE, where actually need to specify the 3 properties, plus basis also requires a % or px to not be ignored.